# If an array name is treated as a pointer, why do I get a compile time error of Lvalue required when incrementing an array?

Tags: c++, c

```
int main()
{
  int a[]={2,3,4,5,6};
  int j;
  for(j=0;j<5;j++)
  {
    printf("%d\n",*a);
    a++; 
  }
  return;
}
```

gives "`Lvalue` required" error but

```
int main()
{
int a[]={2,3,4,5,6};
int *p,j;
p=a;
for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{
  printf("%d\n",*p);
  p++; 
 }
return;
}
```

doesn't. why????

Comment: An array **is not a pointer**. As an id-expression, it is a non-modifiable lvalue. Hence, you cannot change it, similarly `a = p;` is forbidden. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/420683

Answer (score 2):

Though closely related, [arrays are not pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html). The name of the array is just a label to identify some allocated memory (hence, the Lvalue error when you try to modify it).

Comment: N.B. an array name (as an id-expression) *is* an lvalue (you can take its address), but it's not modifiable (you cannot assign something to it).

Comment: The fact that the name of the array is a label to identify some memory is not the cause of the “Lvalue required” error. In fact, a label identify some memory is actually what the `++` operator wants: It wants to operate on an object. In `int x`, the `x` is a label for an `int`, and `x++` works just fine. The actual problem is that the array is automatically converted to a pointer, and the result is a mere value, not an object. If the array were not automatically converted to a pointer, then `a++` would yield an error because `a` is not modifiable, not because it is not an lvalue.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right, it's slightly different for C++, where I "come from" -- in C++'s postfix increment, the *modifiable lvalue* requirement comes first, *then* the requirement on the type, and no array-to-pointer conversion precedes this requirement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, maybe I was not very precise. I was just trying to find a simple way of expressing the idea of the array name being equivalent to a memory location (a number indicating an address), as opposed to a variable. As you stated perfectly well, the problem is not the non-modifiable part, but the not being an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

An array is not a pointer. In most expressions, an array is **converted** to a pointer automatically. The result of this conversion is no longer the array; it is just a pointer **value**.

The `++` operator cannot operate on a mere value. It must have an object to act on.

For example, consider `int x = 3; (x+5)++;`. The result of `x+5` is 8. It is not `x`. The result is just a value, not an object, so there is no object containing 8 that `++` can operate on. This is an error.

Similarly, if `a` is an array of `int`, then `a++` is equivalent to `((int *) a)++`. The `++` is not trying to act on the `a`; it is trying to act on the result of converting `a` to a pointer.

An array expression is always converted to a pointer to the first element except when the array expression is the operand of `sizeof`, `&`, or `_Alignof` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Comment: but when i had incremented array name using ++ operator in the a difffernt program then it was working fine in it

Comment: in it I had passed the array to some other function and then incremented it

Comment: like void foo(int b[][3]){ ++b; b[1][1]=9}

Comment: It had modified the value of array in main() which was sent as a parameter to the function foo.

Comment: @user2645461: The code in `main` does not attempt to modify the array. The assignment `p=a;` assigns the value of a pointer to the array to the pointer `p`. Then `p++` modifies the pointer. Unlike arrays, pointer objects are not converted to anything; they are already pointers. So, in `p++`, `p` provides an object, not just a value, that `++` can work on.

Answer (score 0):

This will display all the array data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[]={2,3,4,5,6};
    int *p,j;
    p=a;
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
         printf("%d\n",p[j]);
     }
   return 0;
}
```